# Multiple drawLayer:

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, core-animation, calayer

how can i use drawLayer for multiple layers in one class?
I was thinking maybe something like this:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    if(layer == layer1) {
        //do this
    }

    if(layer == layer2) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

how would i do that?

Comment: Yes, you would do it exactly like that.

Comment: well then where does the layer1 and layer2 come from? would it have to be declared in the .h?

Comment: You set the layer's delegate to be this object so you must have references to the layers, whether they are ivars/properties of this class or whether you got them from somewhere else.