# How to implement drawLayer:inContext with two layers?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, core-graphics, calayer

Is it possible for me to implement `drawLayer:inContext:` two times, one for each layer?

For example:

```
CALayer *layer1 = [CALayer layer];
layer1.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view.layer addSubLayer:layer1];

CALayer *layer2 = [CALayer layer];
layer2.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view.layer addSubLayer:layer2];
```

Now that I have two layers (aside from the layer already included in the UIView), I want each layer to implement different "actions" depending on their `drawLayer:inContext:` method. So how can I get each layer to perform the specific actions? Should I use `performSelector:`? Please give me any tips or advices. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579795/multiple-drawlayer?rq=1). All you have to do is to keep reference of the layer you are currently using. Then use `if..else...` or switch statement to perform the actions in `drawLayer:inContext:` based on the current layer you are using.